# qclipboard send image to system clipboard

Tags: qt, clipboard

When i try to copy a image into system clipboard(then i can paste it into a ms-word doc),the code below failed,don't know why,even i tried with settext,it also failed.don't know why.

```
QApplication::clipboard()->setPixmap(
        QPixmap("d://20121001154504.png"),
        QClipboard::Clipboard);
```

Comment: Ahh. Can't edit your post... Please, delete 4 spaces in the very start, put empty line before code and add 4 spaces before code.

Comment: Ok. But you didn't add 4 spaces before code. Add them, please, for better looking

Comment: @Marek R tell me, please, how did you bypass '6 non-space characters rule' ? I tried to edit the post, but SO told me, that I can't make changes, because I only inserted 4 spaces.

Comment: is it done?i tried to fit the format,but my english is not so good

Comment: @borisbn: I don't understand your question, I just read help how to use this site, there is lots of cool hints. To gain privilege to edit question of other users you have to have a better score.

Answer (score 4):

First of all [read documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#setPixmap) (use QImage not QPixmap). Then verify that image was loaded properly.

```
QImage image("d://20121001154504.png");
Q_ASSERT(!image.isNull());
QApplication::clipboard()->setImage(image, QClipboard::Clipboard);
```

Comment: I know that setPixmap is Ok, but documentation says it is converted to QImage, so for performance reasons it is better to use setImage.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code (with my path to picture of course) and has the next result:

When I passed this line by debugger (Step Over or `F10` in MSVC), switched to ms-word and tried to paste an image - I got nothing.

When I ran the programm without debugger - I got an appropriate result - an image was pasted in the doc.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QClipboard>
#include <QPixmap>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{   
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    QApplication::clipboard()->setPixmap( QPixmap( "path to my png" ) );
    // if you'll stop here in debugger, you'll have no result

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: yes,i've noticed at the time,if i let the function run to the end,the result is right.why stop here in debugger, I'll have no result?does it mean that in here the coping to clipboard is not finished yet?in fact,i want to add some code here to achieve pasteing the clipboard to a ms-word document,i stop here then to paste by hand check if i have succeed in coping image to clipboard

Comment: "does it mean that in here the coping to clipboard is not finished yet?" I think - you're right. The operation is put into message queue and will processing later (in a.exec();). Try to call `QApplication::processEvents()` just after calling `setPixmap`