# pyqt - copying image to QClipboard crashing program

Tags: python, pyqt

I am writing a PyQt program which I want to be able to copy to the clipboard. Currently I have the following snippet copy the code (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360201/qclipboard-send-image-to-system-clipboard):

```
def copy_to_clipboard(self):
    application=QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not self.image.isNull():
        application.clipboard().setImage(self.image)
```

The code *is* copying the image, but every time it runs, the program crashes. The images aren't insanely huge (about 1000px on a side) and I have copied images much lager than this before (not with Qt).

I am getting the following exit code:

> Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing more than one `QApplication` is likely the cause of the problem (you should only have 1 per process). Rather than constructing a new `QApplication`, just request a reference to the existing once by using `QApplication.instance()`

Comment: Even better, [clipboard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#clipboard) is static, so the OP can just do `QApplication.clipboard().setImage(self.image)`.

Comment: I went with @ekhumoro's comment, as I have never dealt with `QApplication.instance()`.